# VSTS Build - Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.sln build errors

Tags: json.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

See attached image - I'm trying to build 3 Class Library Projects in VSTS all of which include Newtonsoft.Json as a NuGet package - but I'm getting a bunch of errors relating to Newtonsoft tests etc that I am at a loss to resolve.

I've updated all 3 class projects to 4.6.1, I've upgraded all NuGet packages and performed an `Update-Package -reinstall`.

I'm pretty new to VSTS builds, can't find anything relevant on Google around the Newtonsoft tests and I don't know why VSTS is finding references to Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.sln as it's not part of my git repository or projects.

[image: VSTS Build Errors]

Comment: How do you install Newtonsoft.Json pacakge? What're files in the repository? Can you share the log on the OneDrive? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share a sample project on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's trying to build it, it's definitely in your repo.

If you don't want it to build, change the pattern in the Visual Studio Build step to only build the relevant solutions. The default pattern is `**\*.sln`, which will find and attempt to build all the solutions in your repository.

Comment: Thanks for this - you're right it's in some random folder and because of the **\\*.sln it's getting picked up.